# How to Multiply array without numpy and math in pandas csv file

Tags: python, pandas

Halo, im sabil and newbie using python

First of all, i want to multiplle array with index:

> [90,20] with [20,7]

My mentor ask me to not using anything library like (dot,add,etc) but using array

Here is my codefor transpose() :

```
def nilaiWeightTranspose():
    nilaiWTranspose = jumlahBobot
    x,y = jumlahBobot.shape
    hasil = np.zeros((y,x))
    for i in range(y):
        for j in range(x):
            hasil[i,j] = jumlahBobot.iloc[j,i]
    hasilTranspose =  pd.DataFrame(data = hasil[0:,0:])
    return hasilTranspose
```

and output :

> [image]

and here is my code for datanormalisasi():

```
def minmaxnormalization_latih(dropdata):
    minperfeature = []
    maxperfeature = []
    datanormalisasilatih = datalatih
    for i in range(len(dropdata.columns)):
        minperfeature.append(min(dropdata[dropdata.columns[i]]))
        maxperfeature.append(max(dropdata[dropdata.columns[i]]))
    for i in range(len(datalatih.index)):
        for j in range(len(datalatih.columns)):
            datanormalisasilatih.loc[i, datalatih.columns[j]] =  (datanormalisasilatih.loc[i, datalatih.columns[j]] - minperfeature[j]) / (maxperfeature[j] - minperfeature[j])
    return datanormalisasilatih
```

> [image]
>   [image]

and here is my code if i using library(dot) and succesful :

```
def nilaiHinit():
    hitung_hInit = pd.DataFrame(datanormalisasilatih.values.dot(hasilTranspose.values), columns=jumlahBias.columns)
    hitung_hInit_bias = hitung_hInit
```

the problem is idk how to multiple array without (dot) and i want to multiple array without (dot) or anything, can anyone know how to solve it?
thank you ^^

Comment: https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/matrix-multiplying.html

Comment: i kno men, but i only can use (dot) and my mentor are not allowed to it

Comment: So you can or can't use ```dot```? (In your question you stated, that you can't)

Comment: i can use dot, but my mentor are allowed using dot. He asked me to use (*) and array men.

Comment: But you literally showed that you're using ```dot``` and it's successful. What is your question then, since you are looking for matrix multiplication, and have a working code, with the valid technology?

Comment: ya i know my code are succeessful but my mentor are not allowed me to using dot, and i want to ask you is it the way to multiplication without dot>?

Comment: Yes, please implement the method I shared in the link. It's literally how matrix multiplication is defined mathematically

Comment: ok move to chat